# how to apply a fonction on every element of pandas array python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a little problem, I don't know how to apply my function to every element of my pandas array can anyone help me, please ??

```
def zipper(liste)
    return list(map(list, list(zip(*liste))))

str1 = pd.Series( (v[0] for v in dd) )
resConcat['drawing']=resConcat['drawing'].append(str1)
```

I did try this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Would be best if you could provide an example dataset as well as the expected output

Answer (score 1):

To apply the function on every element of pandas array use **apply** function.

See this documentation on how to use apply function -[pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)